# No persister for proxy only occuring for classes that are inherited and implicit polymorph mapped?

Tags: c#, inheritance, nhibernate-mapping

My entities look like this simplified:
[image: baseobject and product are abstract]

I use xml file mapping. I have a table and a xml file for each class except for the abstract ones. Since I use lazy loading I have many proxies. The strange thing is when I call `Refresh(obj)` one of them it works every time, unless the object is of type Product1Proxy or Product2Proxy. Then I get a "no persister for ...Proxy" error.

**What have I tried?**

- add `<mapping assembly="Project.DomainModel"/>` to the App.config
- checked if all the .hbm.xml files are embedded resources (they are)
- my classes are public
- they have a public default constructor

My NHibernate Version is 3.3.

My last idea is that I should use another mapping for my products, but why would it work with CustomerProxy (and others) then? In my opinion Customer and BaseObject have the same relationship as Product and Product1.

**Could it be the inheritance mapping? Is there another problem I don't see?**

**update:** Now I tried to Unproxy the objects before calling `Refresh(obj)` on them, but the method still returns Product1Proxy for example. Then I tried `myObject is INHibernateProxy` but that always evaluates to false. Why does NHibernate not recognize its own proxies?

**update2:** I just noticed that myObject, that is of Type Product1Proxy states that its baseobject is *Product* and not *Product1*. Am I completely wrong or should this be the case?

**update3:**

```
session.Refresh((NHibernate.Proxy.INHibernateProxy)product);
```

For example this causes an invalid cast Exception (Product1Proxy could not be cast to INHibernateProxy).

```
if (kitProduct is NHibernate.Proxy.INHibernateProxy) {
...
}
```

never is true...

and if I call this

```
IList kitProductTemplates = ProductManager.Instance.LoadProductTemplates(checkBoxShowHidden.Checked);
```

a List of Product1 (the real Product1 is returned, no Proxies), but if I iterate over that list with foreach, the objects are a Proxy. The query looks like this:

```
public IList LoadAllTemplates(bool showHidden)
{
    IList loadedObjects = (IList)new ArrayList();
    try
    {
        ISession session = HibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession();
        ICriteria crit = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Product1));
        crit.Add(Restrictions.Eq("IsTemplate", true));
        crit.SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());
        crit.AddOrder(Order.Asc("Name"));
        crit.SetFetchMode("PickingList", FetchMode.Join);
        crit.SetFetchMode("SOP", FetchMode.Join);

        if (!showHidden) {

            crit.Add(Restrictions.Eq("IsHidden", false));
        }
        loadedObjects = crit.List();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
    return loadedObjects;
}
```

(this I just found out, otherwise I would have added it earlier)

**update4:** I can narrow the problem again. It doesn't occur when it's the session as the object was first loaded. But I can not guarantee that for every possible use case.

Best regards, Expecto

Answer (score 0):

You should have a mapping for the abstract classes that are proxied.

The proxy is generated from the information that is available for NH, without touching the DB (which is the whole sens of having a proxy). When you have a reference to a `Product`, which may be a `Product1` or a `Product2`,, then NH generates a proxy inherited from `Product` (`ProductProxy`). To know if the proxy should actually be a `Product1` or `Product2`, it would have to touch the DB, which is not what we want.

To solve the problem: Map `Product` and map `Product1` and `Product2` by using subclass or joined-subclass. Avoid references to `BaseObject`, to avoid `BaseObjectProxy`'s being generated.

**Edit:** If you still need references to `BaseObject`, use `<any>`.

**Edit 2**: Note that you never know if you get a proxy from a query or not, unless you are at the beginning of the transaction. Whenever a proxy had been created for a product, NH keeps returning this proxy from every query that is returning the same product. Even if the query wouldn't return proxies. This is to make sure that you always get the same instance for the same thing.

Example:

In DB, you have Product1 with ID 1, 2, and 3.

```
// NH creates a proxy.
var proxy = session.Load<Product>(1);

// NH returns all Product1 instances, including the proxy
var allProducts = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Product1)).List();
```

allProducts contains a Proxy with id 1 and Non-Proxies with id 2 and 3.

Comment: can I use union-subclass? I don't want an extra table for Product since it's abstract.

Comment: yes, union-subclass is mapped using the xml element "subclass". Currently you already have two separate tables, with the common base-class properties in both tables. Having a third table may be an options, because it is more normalized.

Comment: I added a note about referencing BaseObject using any.

Comment: I am not yet happy with the answer because I never get a ProductProxy, it's always either Product1Proxy or Product2Proxy. I tell NHibernate which one to choose by `session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Product1))...`. I still wonder why the same problem doesn't appear with Customer and BaseObject if the mapping was the reason.

Comment: I already explained update 2. I don't know why you can't cast to the proxy interface. Can you post some code?

Comment: The items in the list can be mixed proxies and non-proxies. If you can't handle this, it may fail either case. See my explanation in Edit 2.

Comment: ok, I get that they could be mixed. But in my example I get returned a list of product1 (all of them, I checked with the debugger) and as soon as I am in a `foreach (Product1 p in list)` every `p` is a `Product1Proxy`, but the statement `p is INHibernateProxy` evaluates to `false`. There is something going completely wrong and I don't understand what. This is why I am not so sure if the problem is the inheritance mapping, but if you still say so I will try that.